# JPA detach before edit

Tags: java, jpa, orm

What is the difference between the following blocks of code in reference to JPA:

```
 private void sample1(){
    Entity entity=em.find(1);
    em.detach(entity);
    entity.setProperty(property);
    em.persist;
 }
```

and

```
 private void sample2(){
    Entity entity=em.find(1);
    entity.setProperty(property);
    em.merge;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both methods are in a transactional context..

The first method will produce a `EntityExistsException` as you would be trying to persist an entity which already has an id field set. This would be proper code if use merge instead of persist here. If the property you update is the id itself though, then it might work (unless there are some dependencies that have been eagerly loaded then you might stumble upon some problems).

In the second example you do not need to call merge as the entity would be updated upon transaction commit automatically by the persistence provider (on method return).